# Create Sitecore Forms - PropertyGridForm.js error - Sitecore Forms Extensions

Tags: sitecore-forms, tds

I had deployed `Sitecore Forms Extensions` module through my solution (added all the files in project and items through `TDS`). When I create a new form and start adding fields/sections, I am getting following `js` error in console in the `PropertGridForm.js`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
at Object.initialize (VM4858 PropertyGridForm.js:17)
at callMethodIfExists (sitecore.js:2817)
at LifeCycleIterator.runOn (sitecore.js:2837)
at AppManager.start (sitecore.js:2457)
at sitecore.js:418
at sitecore.js:332
at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
at Module.check (require.js:866)
at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
at require.js:132
```

The error is occurring on the following line of the `js` file.

[image]

The loader keeps on spinning and not loading the fields to edit or update.

[image]

In local I have installed the `Sitecore Forms Extensions` module and then `synced` the items to `TDS` which is deployed to the higher environments.

Have anybody faced this issue?

Please help me on the same.

Comment: Did you also deploy the .js files that are included with the module?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Sitecore / SFE are you using? For me updating to 2.2 resolved the issue. See https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/downloads/Sitecore%209.1/Sitecore%20Forms%20Extensions%20for%20Sitecore%209.1-2.2.zip

Comment: I am using the version 1.8.2 which is supported for 9.0 Update 2 sitecore version

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. This was because of the FieldBindingsTokenDatasource and this is missing from Presentation Details of the PropertyGridForm item. The presentation was not overwritten after the TDS sync. I deployed it again changing deployment properties to "Deploy Always" and then it started working. 
I have explained the issue in the blog :

https://codeandlearnspot.wordpress.com/2019/07/14/sitecore-forms-extensions-tds-sync-propertygridform-js-error/